# NextJS <Link> doesn't work in production (Vercel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I just deployed my NextJS site to Vercel. Locally I can navigate between my pages, let's say to "/workshop". But **in production** nothing happens when I click the Workshop button, it doesn't redirect. **The Workshop button is in the Navbar.js**.

```
<Link href="/workshop">
  <button className={styles.button}>Workshop</button>
</Link>
```

Tried this one too

```
<Link href="/workshop">
  <a>
    <button className={styles.button}>Workshop</button>
  </a>
</Link>
```

or

```
<Link href="/workshop" passHref>
   <MyButton />
</Link>
```

or

```
<Link href="/workshop">
    <a className={styles.button}>Workshop</a>
</Link>
```

It doesn't redirect to the workshop page in production.

Folder structure:

```
pages
  _app.js
  _document.js
  index.js
  workshop.js
```

My _app.js:

```
...
<Navbar />

<Component {...pageProps} />

<Footer />
...
```

My index.js:

```
export default function Index() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Services />
            <Work />
            <Contact />
        </>
    );
}
```

My workshop.js looks almost identical.

What did I miss?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, locally it works but in production (on Vercel) it doesn't. Isn't it about my Navbar or SSR / static rendering on first load?

Comment: Check the console for any errors.

Comment: No error in the console, nothing on the network tab either.

Comment: If I go directly to mysite.com/workshop then it doesn't even render it correctly, parts/functions are missing, only in production.

Comment: Please provide your source code (a github repo link would be ideal). Otherwise, please refer to the [mcve guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... **not related to Next.js or Link**.

The **AOS** React library (Animate On Scroll) was interfering with the project and refused to load the workshop page.